# Wordpress Host and Domain Migration

Tags: mysql, wordpress, host

I am moving/migrating a Wordpress Blog from Hostgator to IPage but having a lot of problems with this process, in the process I have changed the domain.
This is what I’ve done so far

1.) Installed a Fresh wordpress on IPage after removing the old one.
2.) Transfer and replaced all the files from Hostgator to IPage, except the wp-config file.
3.) Drop all the Database table on IPage, and then upload the database from Hostgator.
4.) I changed the siteurl are the wp_option to my new domain.

At the moment when I go to the URL it just redirects to Wordpress installation page.  I have no idea what is going on, been banging my head at it for 6 hours.  I read all the other similar issues on Stackoverflow but can’t figure it out.  Note: I am a newb, so please explain it to me as if I was a 3 year old kid.  Thanks!

Comment: did you try going through the installation process, then just overwriting the database when you're done?

Comment: I did not try that.  Is that what your suppose to do?  Shouldn't it just work after you overwrite the database?  I did try to delete the install.php, but it still redirects except it goes to an error 404 page obviously.

Comment: No I agree it should work, but for all we know something got lost in the mix that running the install may fix. once the install is run, if that works you should be able to drop the default tables and import yours

Comment: Tried your suggestion but no success.  When I drop all the tables and re upload it again, it goes straight back to redirecting to install page.

Comment: did you create a wp-config file for the new domain?

Comment: Do you have many posts? if not just install wordpress normaly and then drop the mysql tables and upload your mysql file. then build your website from zero. it will take some work but at least you have all the posts and no problems with that

Answer (score 0):

I transfered a wordpress site recently to a new server so I'll describe the whole process here, I think you'd need just one step here if you're only making domain change.

---

First you zip your whole site, so the root folder with wp-config. Then you move it to your new site. You backup your old base in phpMyAdmin if possible, then in the cpanel of the new page you create new base and import the old one in.

It's important that during this process you **DO NOT OPEN THE NEW SITE IN BROWSER!!!** Otherwise you'll have issues with links etc.

You change your wp-config info so that it corresponds to the new base (base name, username, pass and auth keyes). Next you download this little cool script [link here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB).

You'll extract it to folder `sr`. Upload that folder in the root of your new site. Now you can go to `www.newsite.com/sr` folder, and just search old site address without http:// or www, so search `oldsite.com` and replace it with `newsite.com`. You can then do dry run to see what lines in your tables will be replaced, and if all is ok, just do live run.

Then all your tables should be connected with new site link. Also after that go to permalink settings, and just change options a bit, that wil 'restart' permalinks to new site, and you should be ok.

Also it's better to have most of the plugins disabled. I had plugin that changed the `/wp-admin` for login to some other link (security reasons), but that also meant that I couldn't log in, so I had to delete that plugin, and all worked well.

---

Now, if you're just replacing the domain, I think you should only do the part with search and replace, and then check the permalinks as described.

Hope this helps