# Blank screen after importing database to my local xamp server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I exported all the tables from phpmyadmin and imported the database to my database at my xamp server.

after that i downloaded all the wordpress files from my old hosting and transferred them to my theme in folder.

Finally i updated the database username and password in wp-config.php and also change the

> define('WP_DEBUG', false);

to

> define('WP_DEBUG', true);

But when i preview my website it shows blank white screen.

Moreover,I want to say I make new folder in htdocs folder and put the wordpress files init and then make a new folder in theme folder(sub folders of htdocs) and past my all theme files in it.

Comment: have you change site url ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25989421/629127 I gave the answer about site migration here, and you can check the article I wrote about manually migrating sites [here](http://madebydenis.com/manually-migrate-locally-developed-wordpress-site-to-a-live-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you change site url and home url?

Answer (score 0):

Blank Screen can appear due to several reasons .

1 ) Remove whitespaces in your code.

2 ) Please check is there any error in your code , once due to metabox code error i had same issue.

3 ) **Export** database then try to replace your domain with the current localhost domain/or which ever you want using some editor (sublime/brackets/etc). Then **Import** db .

Comment: Thanks its helpful to me! but not enough. :(

Answer (score 0):

To expand slightly on SJP's answer - a common cause of this is the functions.php file in your theme.

Make sure the first line has no whitespace at the start and the end of this file.

Answer (score 0):

**Option1:** Check you log file

**Option 2:** Go to wp-config.php, set WP_DEBUG to true and see what happens.

**Option 3:** deactivate your all plugin. 
Once you do that, go back to your /wp-content/ folder and rename “plugins.deactivate” back to plugins.

Thanks